# Alternative to post or pre-pruning

Tags: cart, pruning

Usually, to better generalize and have a better understandability of the underlying model, we prune the decision trees. And in some cases, it is still large and difficult to interpret. Is there any other technique (***not*** pruning) that I can apply to make the tree smaller?

Comment: Pruning by definition means making the tree smaller

Comment: @rapaio.: Yes it does, but even after that suppose it is big. How can you reduce the size further? I am curious what other alternative strategies are there

Comment: Hi @user27286. Have a look at the 'optimal decision tree' literature such as the IAI package in R/Python. It eliminates the need for pruning by using global optimisation.